# Orthonormality condition in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, probability, born-rule

What does the orthonormality condition in quantum mechanics truly signify? Does it have a physical meaning? Or is it just a method of normalization applied in order to find the probabilities?

Comment: What precisely do you mean by 'the orthonormality condition'?

Comment: The orthonormality condition is just a property imposed on the basis of the vector space where quantum states are defined. It is not necessary, in the sense that any basis is a valid basis, but is useful when doing calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To help clarify the OP’s question, I believe that they are referring to the following statement:

$$
\int \psi_m(x)^*\psi_n(x)\ dx = \delta_{mn} =
\begin{cases}
  1 \qquad m = n\\
  0 \qquad m\neq n
\end{cases}
$$

where the $\psi_i(x)$ are solutions to the time-independent Schrödinger equation. So the OP’s question can be more accurately asked, *“What does it mean for the solutions of the TISE to be orthonormal?”*

**Orthonormality** is a combination of the properties of orthogonality and normality.

**Normality** just means that the probability density of finding a particle in an eigenstate $\psi_n$ immediately after you’ve prepared it in the same state, *somewhere* in the universe, is 100%:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \psi_m(x)^*\psi_n(x)\ dx = 1 \qquad m = n.$$

**Orthogonality** states that, for a given state $\Psi$, which can be represented as the linear combination

$$ \Psi(x, t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n \psi_n(x)e^{-iE_nt/\hbar}$$

of separable$^1$ solutions $\psi_n(x)$, these solutions constitute the basis states of a Hilbert space of eigenfunctions. By definition, each such solution must be linearly independent of (and, because they are also normalized, orthogonal to) every other solution. In other words,

$$ \int \psi_m(x)^*\psi_n(x)\ dx = 0 \qquad m\neq n.$$

In practical terms, this means that **a particle prepared in an eigenstate $\psi_m$ will never be found in a different eigenstate $\psi_n$ immediately after an observation**.

1. Separable solutions are those which satisfy the ansatz $\Psi(x,t) = \psi(x)\phi(t)$.

Comment: This answer makes almost no mathematical sense. Separability doesn't apply to solutions but to Hilbert spaces. The eigenfunctions forming a Hilbert space has nothing to do with orthogonality (orthogonality of what, anyway?)

Comment: The eigenfunctions are basis vectors of a Hilbert space, therefore they are orthogonal to one another. Separability in the context of what I wrote above simply refers to the ansatz that we write the time-dependent $\Psi(x,t)$ as $ \psi(x)\phi(t)$.

Comment: It sounds like you are approaching QM from a different background in mathematical physics and aren’t accustomed to the conventions used here, hence your confusion about “separability” (which has a completely different definition w.r.t. Hilbert spaces) as well as you not understanding what the OP meant about “the orthonormality condition.” I would kindly ask that you remove your downvote of both the OP’s and my posts unless you have further objections. Thanks! :)

Comment: Indeed I misunderstood the terminology. Perhaps it'd be clearer to call them solutions of the time-independent Schrodinger equation, or eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonian operator. I still find the answer mathematically confusing. For one thing, you are conflating linear independence with orthogonality; if the point of the question is to clarify the concept of orthogonality, we must be careful to separate these distinct notions.

Comment: Secondly, I don't know what the OP meant by 'the orthonormality condition', and it wasn't me who downvoted them, but I do not think it relates to the fact that the eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonian span (rather than constitute) a Hilbert space.

Comment: My apologies, I assumed that the timing of the downvotes and your comments were correlated. Thanks for your suggestions; I’ve edited my answer to clarify the OP’s question and to also explain the linear independence -> orthogonality link. If you have more ideas on how to formalize my proof I’d really appreciate it!

Comment: Good answer. But for your second equation writing $\psi_n(x)^* \psi_n(x)$ would be a little clearer and more conventional, I think.